# UIView does not have a member named 'delegate

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, swift

A bit bizarre, but I can't seem to set a delegate for `UIView` objects. Where did that property go?

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    // Properties
    var subView: UIView!
    var subSubView: UIView!

    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        println("init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder)")

        subView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 100, y: 100, width: 100, height: 100))
        subSubView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 10, y: 10, width: 80, height: 80))

        subView.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
        subSubView.backgroundColor = UIColor.blueColor()

        subView.delegate = self    // Error
        subSubView.delegate = self // Error
    }
}
```

I need the delegate so that I can observe the lifecycle of my subviews.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`UIView` doesn't have (and has never had) a property called `delegate`.

This is why you're getting this error.

Are you sure you're not supposed to be using a custom subclass of `UIView` that you have written?

If not, why are you trying to set the `delegate` of a `UIView`. What is it you're trying to actually do?

Comment: OK, my bad then. I want my controller to get notified when certain views get to layout their subviews. How does one do that?

Comment: There is a method on the viewController `viewDidLayoutSubViews`. That will get called when the views (or subViews) have run `layoutSubViews`.

Comment: It only gets called once, but I have multiple levels of subviews. I want to see when each one of my subviews starts layout.

Comment: You'll have to explain in a bit more detail what is happening and why you need to get notified. `viewDidLayoutSubViews` gets called every time the view changes and lays out its subViews. (and subSubViews etc...)

Comment: Will do, but first I need to research this a bit by myself. Thanks for the answer! I'll accept it asap.